# Conflict in chosing files for MDSPathFilter

Tags: metadata

Class MDSPathFilter is implemented in both

/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/
Metadata (0x7fff9a7d1420)

and

/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/
Support/mdbulkimport (0x10ad41948).

One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Saw a similar question, but answer will be very different for mine. Thanks for any help proffered. I've suspected indexing problems slowing me down for some while. Maybe this is the culprit, maybe not ...